# LINQ XML - add element go in Null Exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq, null

when i execute the code below, for add an element in an XML file, i retrive a
"System.NullReferenceException", whit the detailed: "System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) return null".
I can't explain why.
The file exist and also the element in it.

Im using the following code:

```
 XDocument COCOPrivsSession = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(Properties.Settings.Default.pathData) + "currentSession_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".xml");
                   
                    COCOPrivsSession.Element("PRIVSEVENTS").Element("Priv_" + PrivNumber.ToString()).Add(
                       new XElement("Session_" + (COCOPrivsSession.Elements("Priv_" + PrivNumber).Count() + 1).ToString(), 
                            new XElement("hostName", cbHOSTSelector.Text.ToString()),
                            new XElement("startTime", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss")),
                            new XElement("dedicatedTime_seconds", Program.MainFRMHome.TimeLeft_Priv[PrivNumber].ToString()),
                            new XElement("calculatedEndTime", System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Program.MainFRMHome.TimeLeft_Priv[PrivNumber]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss"))
                    )
                       );

                    COCOPrivsSession.Save(Path.GetFullPath(Properties.Settings.Default.pathData) + "currentSession_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".xml");
```

and this is the XML root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--SESSIONE CORRENTE-->
<CURRENTSESSION>
  <SESSION_INFO>
    <Origin>
      <siteVersion>1.9</siteVersion>
      <siteName>COCOTimer</siteName>
      <xmlVersion>0.2</xmlVersion>
    </Origin>
    <currentSession>
      <startDate />09/02/2021 18:11:48</currentSession>
  </SESSION_INFO>
  <PRIVSEVENTS>
    <Priv_1 />
    <Priv_2 />
    <Priv_3 />
    <Priv_4 />
    <Priv_5 />
    <Priv_6 />
    <Priv_7 />
    <Priv_8 />
    <Priv_9 />
    <Priv_10 />
    <Priv_11 />
    <Priv_12 />
    <Priv_13 />
    <Priv_14 />
    <Priv_15 />
  </PRIVSEVENTS>
</CURRENTSESSION>
```

has anyone had the same or similar problem and solved it?

EDIT:
The answer of jdweng solved my issue.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are writing the xml document explicitly?  If you used [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0) you could deal with a class directly instead.  This isn't a solution to your problem but a possible direction you could take to decrease some of the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Hi @FelixCastor. Thanks for your comment. 
No, im just new whit XML handling and im just trying different way to handle whit it.
Under your advise im going to try XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is tested an works :

```
           XDocument COCOPrivsSession = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string PrivNumber = "1";
            string host = "host";
            string timeLeft = "1234";
            int seconds = 10;

            XElement PRIVSEVENTS = COCOPrivsSession.Descendants("PRIVSEVENTS").FirstOrDefault();
                
            PRIVSEVENTS.Add(
                 new XElement("Session_" + (COCOPrivsSession.Elements("Priv_" + PrivNumber).Count() + 1).ToString(),
                 new XElement("hostName", host),
                 new XElement("startTime", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss")),
                 new XElement("dedicatedTime_seconds", timeLeft),
                 new XElement("calculatedEndTime", System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss"))
                 )
            );
```

Comment: With "descendats" it works!
Thanks so much.
I'm new to linq XML and still get lost in its features.